# Git tagging with stash and sourcetree

Tags: git, git-stash

I am trying to migrate from SVN to get what I understood is that

  a trunk is a master

  a tag is a Tag

  a branch is a branch

I have a lots of released versions tags that I want to move in the repo, So what I did is a new repo on the stash

  I started with version 1 revision 1 and was fine

  I used sourcetree to tag it since stash cannot tag

  Then I tried to push version 2 like this

  I pushed it as origin master

`git push origin master`

  I added a commit for it

  and when I try to do a git remote add for the new version I get an error

```
! [rejected]  master -> master (fetch first)
```

I don't want to mess the revision I have already and I only want push it and then tag it, I don't know what will happen if I pull i assume it will be messed up. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try pushing version after version.

Use a [script like svn2git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24773408/6309), or an even more robust tool like [subgit](http://subgit.com/): those will convert your SVN repo in a git repo, respecting your branches and tags.